# R cairo_pdf: How to set default font

Tags: r, plot, fonts

I can achieve my desired output per plot by issuing

```
cairo_pdf("test.pdf", family = "Liberation Sans")
plot(1:10, (1:10)^2, xlab=enc2utf8("α"))
dev.off()
```

My question is: How can I make `family = "Liberation Sans"` the default so that I can omit that?

EDIT: Clarification

Can I make 'Liberation Sans' the default choice for cairo_pdf without re-defining that function (or defining a different one)?  I was hoping that `pdfFonts()` could be useful here.

Comment: Thanks, I am aware of this possibility. But this is not what I am looking for.  I was hoping to change the default font without the need for that helper function.

Comment: I understand that. But this only affects the look of things, so I'd be less worried.  And in that case, the result is system-dependent anyway since the font and font-mapping are taken from the system.